# insert a number orderly into a linked list

Tags: c++

I generate a series of random numbers and push back them into to a vector. Then I want to insert them orderly into a linked list one by one and print the list. However it always throws error.

```
#include"std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <chrono>

#define N 100
int random_numbers()
{
    random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, N);
    int a = 0;
    a = dis(gen);
    return  a;
}

vector<int> randoms;
void get_random_numbers()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        randoms.push_back(random_numbers());
    }
}


void insert_in_lists()
{

    list<int> l ;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        list<int>::iterator it = l.begin();
        if (i = 0)
        {
            l.insert(it, randoms[i]);
        }
        else 
        {
            for (list<int>::iterator p = l.begin(); p != l.end(); p++)
            {

                if (randoms[i]<= *p)
                {
                    it = p;
                    //break;
                }
            }
            l.insert(it, randoms[i]);
        }       
    }
    for (list<int>::iterator p = l.begin(); p != l.end(); p++)
    {

        cout << *p << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    get_random_numbers()
    insert_in_lists();


    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

I wanna get a series of sorted number like: 
1 2 2 2 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 6 7 .......

ERROR:Unhandled exception at 0x74F608B2 in Problem06.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Range_error at memory location 0x00EFF884.

Comment: Where do you call `get_random_numbers`? You appear to be reading `randoms` before putting numbers into it, which is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: I edited it, but still doesn't work.

Comment: `if (i = 0)` = is an assignment not a comparison. change that to `if (i == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

It's so much simpler:

```
#define N 100

vector<int> get_random_numbers()
{
    random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, N);

    vector<int> randoms(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        randoms[i] = dis(gen);
    }
    return randoms;
}

void insert_in_lists()
{
    vector<int> randoms = get_random_numbers();
    sort(randoms.begin(), randoms.end());
    list<int> l(randoms.begin(), randoms.end());
    for (list<int>::iterator p = l.begin(); p != l.end(); p++)
    {
        cout << *p << endl;
    }
}
```

This way, we efficiently construct and sort the vector, then copy its values to the list.  This will be much faster, and the code is much simpler.